# mongodb & mongoose: How to auto create new collection when saving a document in it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**Program description:** I have a program that accepts a post request (`request`) of a "hometask" with its `name`, `description`, `importance` and `group` parameters provided. I need the provided group parameter to be identified as a collection name in the database (each collection is going to correspond to specific group and so each group will have a collection of hometasks-documents). Each new document should be created with Mongoose schema object.

**Problem:** I know that in Python's `pymongo` when addressing an unexisting collection it's being created automatically, however, in mongoose this turns out not to be the case. I have trouble providing the collection name to the new document-object. When providing `{collection: request.group}` in a new object in `api/hometask.js`, the error message started appearing when new requests were made: **`MongooseError: document must have an _id before saving`**. I still cannot understand what can be the cause of this problem. I will appreciate any help!

- Main folder architecture:

[image]

- server.js

```
const express = require('express')
require('dotenv').config()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const path = require('path')

let app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
mongoose.connect(process.env.uri, { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(db => console.log('[ok] connected to db))
.catch(err => console.error(err))

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use('/api/hometasks', require('./api/hometask'))
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist')))
app.listen(port)
```

- api/hometask.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Record = require('../models/hometask')

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    let request = req.body
    const record = new Record(request, {collection:request.group});
    try {
        await record.save();
        res.json({
            status: 'success'
        });  
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

- models/hometask.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

let Record = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  importance: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  group: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('hometask', Record);
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [`autoCreate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#autoCreate) option when creating the schema?

Comment: @boranseckin yes, I get the same `MongooseError: document must have an _id before saving` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mongoose the collection name is set per model, not per document.

Note that the [Model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model) constructor does not take an options object.

You should be setting the collection name in the call to [mongoose.model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-model) when you create the model, not when you create a document from that model.

Comment: Thank you for explaining how it works, it has been really helpful!